# Is it possible to have two different hover actions in one svg area?

Tags: php, html, css, svg

I am learning SVG and using css hover effects to have a minimalist-looking graph in which details appear as your mouse hovers. I am running up against an apparent limitation in that once a particular piece of "real estate" in my svg element has a hover effect assigned to it, I cannot figure out a way to have another overlapping element in the same spot with a different hover effect.

This are pics of my chart:

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODwK9.png), [second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kaob.png) and [third picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y7HC.png).

The first image is the minimalist chart with no hover. The second image is when a person hovers over one of the bars--as you can see, weekly kilometers appear. In the third image, when the person hovers anywhere in my transparent rectangle (which occupies the entire bottom two-thirds of the chart) the x-axis description of weeks appears.

The problem I am having is that the user in this setup can see EITHER the x-axis or the kilometer value. They can't see both. I would like to have my x-axis appear upon mouse-over at any place in the entire rectangle. Currently, it works everywhere except in the bar areas. I don't want the bar areas "excluded" from the mouseover effect!

This is my simplified code. The "goosegg" appears when there are no kilometers ridden in the week; I left that code out for simplicity.

```
    <?php
            //The invisible rectangle and x-axis
            echo "<g class = \"axis\"><rect style = \"fill: pink; opacity: 0;\" width = \"590\" height = \"240\"";
            echo "x =\"0\"";
            echo "y = \"100\"></rect>";
            echo "<text y = \"357\" x = \"";
            echo "20";
            echo "\" dy = \".35em\">";
            echo "<tspan x = \"22\">Week 0</tspan><tspan x = \"92\">Week 1</tspan><tspan x = \"162\">Week 2</tspan><tspan x = \"232\">Week 3</tspan><tspan x = \"302\">Week 4</tspan><tspan x = \"372\">Week 5</tspan><tspan x = \"442\">Week 6</tspan><tspan  x = \"512\">Week 7</tspan>";
            echo "</text>";
            echo "</g>";

               //displays bars with kilometers and km value mouseover
               for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                ?>
                <g class="bar">
                <rect width="60" height="<?php echo round($sums_for_tabletest[$i]); ?>" x="<?php echo (20 + ($i * 70)); ?>"
                      y="<?php echo(340 - round($sums_for_tabletest[$i])); ?>"></rect>
                <?php

                echo "<text y=\"";
                echo(330 - round($sums_for_tabletest[$i]));
                echo "\" x = \"";
                if (round($sums_for_tabletest[$i]) < 100) {
                    echo(40 + ($i * 70));
                } elseif (round($sums_for_tabletest[$i]) < 10) {
                    echo(38 + ($i * 70));
                } else {
                    echo(39 + ($i * 70));
                }
                 echo "\" dy=\".35em\">";
                echo round($sums_for_tabletest[$i]);
                echo "</text>";
                echo "</g>";
                }
```

And the CSS:

```
.axis {
  fill: pink;
}
.axis text {
   fill:  #ab1d98;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.axis:hover text,
.axis:focus text {
   opacity: 1;
    fill:  #ab1d98;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.bar {
    fill: #600a58;
    height: 41px;
    transition: fill .3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

.bar text {
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: 800;
    opacity: 0;
}

.bar:hover,
.bar:focus {
    fill: #ffff99;
}

.bar:hover text,
.bar:focus text {
    fill: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

So to sum it all up, I'm looking for a way to make the x-axis visible when mouseover anywhere in the entire transparent "axis" class rectangle area, not just in the rectangle areas that aren't part of the "bar" class. I am looking primarily for a svg/css only solution. If it is possible only via javascript, that also will be helpful to know and I can implement it in a few weeks when I actually get to learning javascript; I'm a newbie and want to get svg fundamentals down before I add javascript to my code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation it seems that the elements are not related to one another. The same rules apply to SVG as to regular HTML: a hover effect will propagate up the CSS Object Model but it's difficult and not recommended to connect arbitrary parts of SVG together through HTML.

A suggestion would be to have the axis show up when you hover over any part of the chart. In this case, assuming that everything is wrapped up in `.chart`, the contents could be something like

```
<g class="chart">
    <g class="bar">
    <g class="bar">
    <g class="bar">
    <g class="bar">
    <g class="axis">
</g>
```

Then your effect could be something like

```
.chart
.chart:hover .axis { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. So is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with just svg/css? I tried making both the x-axis legend and the numbers over the bars into "bar" class, but then it appears I was stuck with the same color text for both. And ideally, I would like the x-axis to appear on mouseover anywhere in the bottom one-third of the chart.

Comment: I am removing my previous comment to do further testing!

Comment: Thank you @ moscar! In attempting to implement your suggestion, I discovered an error in my code involving the placement of a </g>. I think this error may have been what was causing my original code not to work as intended. However, your suggestion was simpler and clearer and easy to work with; this made it easier to find the error and get it working. So I'm marking this answer as accepted!